# Why does the first data READ always take the longest?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5, offline

I have an offline-enabled mobile app built using SAPUI5 (A Javascript Framework) and deployed as a Hybrid App in SAP Cloud Platform (Which packages it up as a Cordova app for Android).

The strange thing is, the first batch of data (oData) requests ran after login ALWAYS take the longest. (Say 13 seconds to populate my view model). These are simply a sequence of READ requests on the offline store.

Every request after that, even for the exact same model object, is a lot faster, say 2-3 seconds.

Is there a reason for this? The architecture of the device maybe?

NOTE: The view model is being populated with new data each time.

Comment: Hi adams, have you compared the headers of the first request with the second using developer tools under network are they same or different? Another thing may be to ask the backend guy to trace on his side when the request reaches the backend system first time.

Comment: It's an offline store on the app so there is no backend guy :(

Comment: Hi adam, so where are you reading data from on first load?

Comment: I've populated the offline data before I get to this issue....

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry to ask but has the following helped you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611468/how-to-load-sapui5-resources-in-the-background

Comment: Hi.  No not really.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the issue was not with the READ. Rather the first REFRESH of the view model.

I'll raise another Q on this...